# Mule:Transaction manager for subflow

Tags: transactions, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Trying to implement a transaction approach for a mule flow which contains various subflows and each subflow contains some database inserts in spring bean using invoke component.

```
<amqp:inbound>
    <flow ref="subflow1">
    <flow ref="subflow2">
    <flow ref="subflow3">
<amqp:outbound>
```

where subflow1 and subflow 2 both contains call to service bean which is calling DAO database operations(using hibernate session).Subflow3 is call to external system.

```
<flow name="subflow1">
        <invoke object-ref="serviceBean" method="databaseOperation" methodArguments="#[message.inboundProperties]"/>
</flow>
```

Suggest best approach of implement transaction manager in a way that if any of the subflow fails all insert statement done in earlier subflows should roll back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Put a `transactional` scope around your flow refs,
- Use `sub-flow` instead of `flow` for your sub-flows so exceptions happening in them will bubble up to the transactional scope of the caller flow.

Comment: Thanks @david.But is not better to use flow as we can specify exception strategy for the flow otherwise in subflow it will inherit the exception strategy of main flow.

Comment: You can use `flow`s but you have to be extremely careful with your local exception strategies to avoid preventing a transaction roll back if this needed.